# Try inside catch to ensure finally executes

Tags: c#, .net, exception, try-catch, try-catch-finally

I have to process items off a queue.

Deleting items off the queue is a manual call to `Queue.DeleteMessage`.  This needs to occurs regardless of whether or not the processing succeeds.

```
var queueMessage = Queue.GetMessage();

try
{
    pipeline.Process(queueMessage);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    try
    {
        Logger.LogException(ex);
    }
    catch { }
}
finally
{
    Queue.DeleteMessage(queueMessage);
}
```

**Problem:**

On failure, I log the error to some data store.  If this logging fails (perhaps the data store is not available), I still need the message to be deleted from the queue.

I have wrapped the `LogException` call in another `try catch`.  Is this the correct way or performing thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following code is enough. `finally` blocks execute even when exception is thrown in `catch` block.

```
var queueMessage = Queue.GetMessage();    
try
{
    pipeline.Process(queueMessage);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Logger.LogException(ex);
}
finally
{
    Queue.DeleteMessage(queueMessage);//Will be executed for sure*
}
```

Comment: `finally blocks execute even when exception is thrown in catch block.` - I did not realise this.  Perfect, thanks.

Comment: @Alireza `it remains unhandled` unless and until it is caught somwehere else

Comment: The difference between what you proposed and the PO's is that his code catches any catchable exceptions

Answer (score 1):

The finally block always executes, even if it throws an unhandled error (unless it end the app). So yes.